# How to install fonts for TeX Live

Tags: software-installation, fonts

Kindly advise how to install fonts-arabeyes fonts-kacst, please.  I'm trying to install TeX live on Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (pre-release).

Answer (score 1):

I think that

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra fonts-arabeyes fonts-kacst
```

would be enough.